# Is there a way to make `git switch` display what local files it is changing as it's progressing?

Tags: git

I find it a bit unnerving that `git switch` changes a bunch of local files, but I have no clear idea what, unless I diff the branches explicitly.

I was hoping that `git switch --progress` would show me that, but alas it still doesn't show anything, although the branches I switch clearly differ (as shown by `git diff`) and I even get "files changed on disk" notifications in my editor while/after `git switch` is running.

So, is there a way to make `git switch` show what it is doing to locally checked-out files (not as fully as a diff, just a one line status per file actually changed would do), as it is changing those files?

(I'm using git version 2.25.1.)

Comment: I doubt you'll get that from the switch command, it's a no frills, switch to branch command. If you simply want a listing of the files that are going to be changed, why not use the `--name-only` switch for the `diff` command? (or any combination of the other switches) Then make an alias to combine them as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no: you will have to get used to this behavior.  (It may help to know just what Git is doing and why.)

As [Jeff Mercado mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718904/is-there-a-way-to-make-git-switch-display-what-local-files-it-is-changing-as-i#comment107428481_60718904), you *can* get `git diff` to tell you what a future `git switch` will do.  Note that `git diff`'s main job here is to *compare two commits* or *compare one commit to the work-tree*.<sup>1</sup>  In other words, we extract the first commit into a temporary area, then extract the second commit into a temporary area—or use the work-tree instead of the second commit—and compare them, with the first commit on the "left side" of the comparison and the second on the "right side"

If you just run `git diff commit-specifier` with no options at all, Git does such a comparison, then gives you a recipe to follow: *add this new file, delete this file entirely, delete these lines from file A, add these lines to file B* and so on.  Following this recipe will change the left-side commit to the right-side one (or to match the work-tree).

If you add the `--name-only` option, Git tells you *less:* instead of giving you the recipe, it just lists the *names of files that would be added, removed, or modified*.

If you use instead the `--name-status` option, Git tells you an in-between amount: it still lists the names of the files, but this time it prefixes each one with a letter code: `A` for *add this file*, `D` for *delete this file*, and `M` for *modify this file in place*.  (There are some more letter codes; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for all the details.)

Hence:

```
git diff otherbranch
```

gives you a recipe for taking the snapshot represented by the *last* commit of the branch named `otherbranch`, and turning that snapshot into what's in your work-tree right now.  So:

```
git diff --name-status otherbranch
```

will tell you what files would have to be *added to* that commit to produce what you have in your work-tree: such files will, in general, be *removed* when you switch to that commit.  It will tell you what files would have to be *deleted* from that commit to produce what you have in your work-tree: such files will, in general, be *added* when you switch to that commit.  And, it will tell you which files would have to be modified.  If you had Git show you what changes would have to be made, then `git checkout otherbranch` will, in effect, make the opposite changes.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git diff` command actually has a number of main jobs, and I'm skipping over the one that you get if you run `git diff` with no arguments at all.  That compares the contents of Git's *index* to the contents of the work-tree.  I'm trying to keep this answer free of information about Git's index, except in these footnotes.

---

#### Why is this all backwards?

The reason the above seems backwards is that this isn't really how this is intended to be used.

Remember, every commit holds a *full and complete snapshot of every file*.  When you make a Git commit, Git saves—forever<sup>2</sup>—a frozen, compressed, read-only, Git-only snapshot of *every file* you told Git about.<sup>3</sup>  These frozen and Git-ified copies of the files can never be changed, and will live as long as the commit does (see footnote 2).

But only *Git* can use these files.  That means these commits are fine as archives, but useless for getting any actual work done.  To *use* a commit, you have to get Git to extract it, turning all the frozen, Git-ified files into ordinary everyday files that you can see and work with.

Those ordinary files go into your *work-tree*.  These are the files you can open in your editor.  Hence the whole point of `git switch` (or in older versions of Git, `git checkout`) is to *replace the entire work-tree* with one from some *other* commit.  Since every commit has a complete snapshot of *all* files, it only makes sense to remove this one, and check out / switch to a different one.

So this kind of `git diff` is perhaps most useful when run just as:

```
git diff HEAD
```

which compares what's in the *current commit*—the one you selected earlier with `git switch`—to what's in the work-tree right now.  Any differences are things that you can `git add` and then `git commit`: your new commit, once you've set it all up with `git add`, will contain the new snapshot based on the files you copied into the index and then committed.  ... Oops, I've gone and mentioned the *index* in the body of the answer.

---

<sup>2</sup>A commit really only sticks around as long as you can *find* it.  Each commit has a unique *hash ID*, and Git has ways to find these hash IDs so that you—and Git—can find the commits.  If you really need to get rid of a commit, it tends to be hard, but you can force Git to "forget" a commit as long as you are willing to forget all of its children as well.  In this case, the commit will eventually be removed via Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, Git makes each new commit from the copies of files that appear in Git's index.  You use `git add` to copy a file from your work-tree into Git's index.  When you switch *to* a commit, Git fills its index from that commit, and then fills your work-tree from what's now in the index.

---

#### A brief overview of the index

The index—this phrasing implies that there's only one, though in fact there's one per work-tree, which matters if you start using `git worktree`—has a lot of roles in Git, and hence has three different names that all mean the same thing.  It's often called the *staging area*, and occasionally—rarely these days—the *cache*.  It does a lot of things but its biggest, main function is that it is where you *build the next commit to make*.

The index contains a copy of each file that will go into the *next* commit.<sup>5</sup>  As mentioned in footnote 3, switching to a commit copies that commit's files out, to both the index *and* your work-tree.  The index's copy of each file is in the frozen Git-only internal format, ready to go into the *next* commit.  The work-tree copy is the one that's useful to *you*, which is why Git writes it into an area that's mainly for *your* use.

You can change the work-tree copy all you want.  That has no effect on the *index* copy.  So, if you *have* changed the work-tree copy, and you'd like the updated file to be in the *next* commit, you now have to run:

```
git add path/to/file
```

to tell Git: *Copy the work-tree copy back into the index, replacing the previous copy there.*  Git will squash the file down into the frozen format, ready to go into the *next* commit.

When you do run `git commit`, Git just packages up whatever is in the index *at that time* and makes that the snapshot for the new commit.  That's why you have to `git add` so often: you need to replace the index copy, now that you've changed the work-tree copy.

You can't change the `HEAD` copy: that's inside a commit, and all commits are frozen for all time.  You can, of course, make a *new* commit, after which Git automatically switches *to* the new commit—so after committing, `HEAD` identifies the new commit, and the new commit's frozen-for-all-time copy matches the index's frozen (but replaceable) copy.  Note how the work-tree copy was irrelevant to this process.

(Git doesn't write *to* your work-tree copy in this automatic-switch-to-new-commit as there's no real actual switching happening.  For way too much on this, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)

---

<sup>5</sup>Technically, the index contains a *reference to* a copy of the file's *content*, in the frozen format.

---

#### Untracked files

It's worth mentioning one last wrinkle.  In all of the above, your work-tree is mostly *yours*, to do with as you will, except for the fact that `git checkout` or `git switch` has to *fill it in* from a commit—which of course replaces all your files.

But since your work-tree *is* yours, you can create files in it that are not now in Git's index.  You can also use `git add` or `git rm` to copy files into the index that were never there before, or remove files from the index that were there (as the result of a switch-or-checkout) so that they're *not* in the index any more.  Either way, it's pretty easy to see that you can create a file in your work-tree that is not in Git's index.

A file that *isn't* in the index *right now* is an *untracked file*.  That's actually pretty simple.  A file is untracked if it's not in the index.  (It needs to be in your work-tree of course.  If it's not in your work-tree either, it's just not there at all, so why are we talking about it?)  Since `git add` puts files into the index, and `git rm` takes them out,<sup>6</sup> you can change a file's status from untracked to tracked, or vice versa.  *This never change any existing commit: the files stored inside a commit are frozen that way for all time.*

*Tracked or untracked* is a property of the *index*, which is temporary in the same way your work-tree is temporary.  *Committed* is permanent, as long as the commit itself continues to exist.  **The purpose of `git switch` is to select a commit and fill in the index-and-work-tree from that commit.**  Git will generally avoid clobbering untracked files you've put into your work-tree, but think of your work-tree as *temporary*, because it is: it's the *commits* that matter, in the end.

---

<sup>6</sup>Oddly, `git add` can *remove* an index copy of a file.  Suppose that `path/to/file` is in the index right now, and *not* in your work-tree for whatever reason (you, or something you ran removed it, probably).  If you now run `git add path/to/file`, Git will *remove* the copy from the index.  This is because `git add` really means *make index match work-tree*, not just *copy from work-tree to index*.